# Write result to test report in MbUnit with Gallio

Tags: mbunit, gallio

Does anybody know if it´s possible to write results to some tracelistener or something that the test-report snaps up and embeds into the test report?

for example, 
var loans = GetLoans(...parameters);
Assert.IsTrue(Loans.Length>0);
TestReport.Write("user has :" +loans.Count);

and then have it show up in the test report!
Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestLog.WriteLine(....)

Also notice that TestLog has support for embedding attachments and creating nested sections within the log.